# Warpping a camera image into 2D Quad without opencv

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, computer-vision, ogre

I'm doing AR application where I have camera pose orientation and position.

Given 4 points in world coordinates, how would I wrap the camera image into 2D quad ?

So given the Right image, I would like to get a 2D quad as shown in the left.

Comment: well you either use a library or you research the necessary maths and implement everything yourself. your question is too broad.

Comment: What you may want is *perspective texture mapping*, but in the *reverse sense*. See [this link](http://www.hugi.scene.org/online/coding/hugi%2025%20-%20coding%20corner%20graphics%20bonz%20texture%20mapping%20part%203.htm) for some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters of perspective transformation matrix could be calculated using system of 8 equations for initial and warped coordinates of points:

```
x1' = (A * x1 + B * y1 + C) / (G * x1 + H * y1 + 1.0)
y1' = (D * x1 + E * y1 + F) / (G * x1 + H * y1 + 1.0)
```

You can find description of perspective transformation math in in [Paul Heckbert article](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2008_fall/Papers/proj.pdf).

Example of implementation (C++): [Antigrain library](http://www.antigrain.com/agg-2.5.zip) (file `agg_trans_perspective.h`)

Comment: This is the answer, my concern now, should I capture the image and apply the above math on the texture that is saved on the disk ?

Comment: I don't know about your disk files, but yes, matrix of persp. transform should be applied to all points. Seems that gray sheet lies below cigarette box, so matrix for it should differ (another plane).

Comment: Sorry for not clarification, I will assign 4 points while the web cam is working , then I will crop that image that, then save it to do disk, then load it, apply the persp. transform on it ?
How would I do it that in OpenGL ? should I do a render to texture ?